# Monitoring geth on AWS EC2

Tags: go-ethereum, aws

I have setup a geth node on AWS for a DAPP I've created.
So there's a specific `geth` process running.

I've found that this shuts down every now and then.  Any recommendations on how I can monitor this process and restart it should it go down?